# how to get sku and product name on the head.php page?

Tags: magento

how to get sku and product name on the head.php (\app\code\core\Mage\Page\Block\Html\head.php) page? thank you.

when i used `$this->_data['sku'];` or `$this->getSku();` are all not work.

Answer (score 4):

The previous answer is fine, except it doesn't check if product exists in registry. So you will get fatal error on non-product pages. Always make a check if variable exists.

```
$product = Mage::registry('current_product');
if ($product) //sometimes need check for instanse, use instanseof
{
    $product->getSku();
}
```

Comment: i am sorry it doesn't work. i put your code in head.php public function setTitle($title){}part. and then add the sku to the title. it not show the product sku in the title part. ....$title.$product->getSku()...

Answer (score 1):

You should be able to pull the current product back from the registry and access the values from that.

```
$product = Mage::registry('current_product');
$product->getSku();
```

Comment: i am sorry it doesn't work. i put your code in head.php public function setTitle($title){}part. and then add the sku to the title. it not show the product sku in the title part. ....$title.$product->getSku()

Comment: What version of Magento are you using?

Answer (score 0):

Working Code:

```
if($_product = Mage::registry('current_product')){
  $id = $_product->getId();
  $sku = $_product->getSku();
}
```